# Question about Diaper lining elastic band?

Tags: diaper

I've noticed that the disposable diapers I use on my children have an elastic band around the legs (blue arrow in image below). Sometimes, if care is not taken, the diaper "flap" (red arrow in image below), will be folded inwards, such that the elastic band (blue arrow) is not against the skin. Does it matter if the elastic (blue arrow) is directly against the skin? Should I bother to make sure that the elastic is against the skin? I'd like to see an official reference on whether it matters, since I have a disagreement with my wife regarding the matter.

I assert that care should be taken to ensure the elastic is directly against the skin, whereas my wife thinks it does not matter at all if the diaper "flap" (red arrow) is folded under, such that the elastic is not directly against the skin.

[image: diaper diagram]

Comment: I don’t have an „official“ source, but what I learned (both being told by my very experienced midwife and from practical experience) is that flap in means leaky diapers. The elastic touching the skin is no problem, both of mine had/have sensitive skin.

Comment: Same experience with our kids: flaps tucked inwards means wet clothes/bedsheets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Huggies](https://www.huggies.com/en-us/tips-advice/diapering/tips/lets-do-the-diaper-step-by-step), the diaper edges shouldn’t be tucked under.

Comment: Great link. According to the link, it says "Make sure the edges of the diaper _haven't_  been tucked under" (emphasis mine). Did you mean to say "shouldn't"? If you add the "not", I'll mark yours as the right answer.

Comment: Yes @Eddified I had rewritten the answer for simplicity and didn’t make that change. My son, in diapers, looks like he has frills on the edge of his diapers - NOT TUCKED UNDER